# Enchant Weapon Property: Favor Attack Speed or % Damage?

Tags: diablo-iii

So I got this new weapon:

[image: Cropped screenshot of Balefire Caster tooltip]

However, it lacks a socket, so I need to replace a primary attribute with a socket. My question is which primary property should I replace? It comes down to increased attack speed or an additional percentage of damage. On a more general note, on a weapon, sould I go for attack speed or %damage ?

Comment: As far as I know, +% Damage doesn't interact with + *elemental* Damage at the moment (physical and normal damage does). This is due to be fixed, but Blizzard haven't confirmed whether or not this will affect already rolled items. So as of now, I think it is best to re-roll the + % Damage, unless you want to bank it until Blizzard fixes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**As a Demon Hunter :**

Reroll attack speed if you already have more than 2.5/2.6 Attacks per Second. At this rate you generate hatred fast enough and the difference between a 1.6 APS weapon and a 1.7 APS weapon won't be that much.

Reroll +8% Damage if you like having a high Attack Speed. This is my case. I have more than 2.8 Attacks per Second which brings a real comfort in-game regarding hatred generation and effect procs (like Night Stalker).

**For the other classes :**

Again, it depends on your build and your personal preference.

- Attack Speed allows you to : proc some effects more often (on weapons or skills), to crit more often, etc. With a Wizard for example, if you use the passive Prodigy, the faster you attack, the faster it generates Arcane Power.
- Raw Damage allows you to set up really high crit and damage. If your spells are not attack speed dependent like Ray of Frost you should go for %damage. The spell will take your Arcane Power more slowly and deals more damage which makes picking %damage over attack speed really important in those kinds of builds. On the same note, a fire Monk does not need attack speed but instead relies on the high damage the fire skills can output.

In the end it's your choice and both are good. You don't have to focus on the number displayed on the weapon but on the crits you actually do in the game and the frequency at which those crits appear. That's the difference between sheet DPS and effective DPS.

Comment: Do the numbers stated here apply regardless of class, or are they specific to the Demon Hunter?  If specific, can you please provide numbers for the other classes, given that this question isn't tagged specifically for DH?