# Enchant Property: Damage vs. Attack Speed %

Tags: diablo-iii

There is a similar question about [enchant properties for weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/164205/25490), however I would want to know what should I favor on a ring(and other items): *Average Damage* or *Attack Speed %*?

Here's an example of an item:

[image]

I know it depends on the other items and the build itself, however what is the basic(or advanced) formula for calculating damage output?

Comment: I believe a calculation is shown here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/165418/enchant-which-weapon-property-attack-speed-or-damage You could maybe do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (advanced) formula to calculate damage is this:

**DMG = (AWD x (WS + AS / 100 x WS) x PS / 100 x CC / 100 x (CHD + 100) / 100) + (AWD x (WS + AS / 100 x WS) x PS / 100 x (1 - CC / 100))**

DMG = Damage you will do

AWD = Average Weapon Damage (don't forget to include your offhand and other items with + average damage)

AS = Attack speed Increase as it is in the Details Tab (10% attack speed = insert 10 into formula)

WS = default Weapon speed

PS = Primary stat (Int for WD and Wizard, ...)

CC = Crit chance (10% crit chance = insert 10 into formula)

CHD = Crit Hit Damage (100% crit hit damage = insert 100 into formula)

If you want to know now if it is more efficient to go for different stats, you just have to apply the formula two times with the two different stats.
If you don't feel confident enough to calculate this on your own just post your stats here and i can do this for you